# Проблема с CheckBox в Диалоговом окне

Tags: java, android, dialog

Я хочу сделать кастомное диалоговое окно, и вроде всё хорошо, но метод findViewById на CheckBox не работает. Не знаю в чём проблема и соответственно, как её решить.

Вот код:

```
final AlertDialog dialog1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(ScreensActivity.this).create();
View inflate = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom,null); dialog1.setView(inflate);

Button back = (Button)inflate.findViewById(R.id.back);  
Button ok = (Button)inflate.findViewById(R.id.ok);   
CheckBox ch1 = (CheckBox)inflate.findViewByld(R.id.checkbox1);   
CheckBox ch2 = (CheckBox)inflate.findViewByld(R.id.checkbox2);   
CheckBox ch3 = (CheckBox)inflate.findViewByld(R.id.checkbox3);

back.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { public void onClick(View view) { _back(); } });    
ok.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { public void onClick(View view) {       
    checkbox1 = ch1.isSelected();   
    checkbox2 = ch2.isSelected();   
    checkbox3 = ch3.isSelected();   
} });

dialog1.show();
```

Помогите пожалуйста!

Comment: Ну тут как миниму возникает желание посмотреть нна layout/custom и спросить - каким образом "не работает" findViewById

Comment: The method findViewById(int) is undefined for the type View

Comment: Это ошибка, которая появляется мне.

Comment: лол. Если я правильно понимаю у вас там не finfViewById, a finfViewByLd

Comment: Сейчас проверю. Может и вправду такая смешная ошибка.

Comment: Как я так ошибся))

Comment: Молчание - золото ))

Comment: стоит больше использовать автодополнение кода, это полностью избавит от таких проблем или это у вас копипаста была и лень набирать код самому

Answer (score 0):

Инфлейтите вьюху:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(ScreensActivity.this);
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom, null);
```

Создаете диалог:

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(ScreensActivity.this);
alertDialog.setView(view);
AlertDialog alert = alertDialog.create();
```

Получаете ссылки на вью элементы:

```
Button back = view.findViewById(R.id.back);  
Button ok = view.findViewById(R.id.ok);   
CheckBox ch1 = view.findViewByld(R.id.checkbox1);   
CheckBox ch2 = view.findViewByld(R.id.checkbox2);   
CheckBox ch3 = view.findViewByld(R.id.checkbox3);
```

И отображаете диалоговое окно:

```
alert.show();
```